# multiple panzoom's on one page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, panzoom

I'm using this [panzoom library](https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom), however I'm struggling to get it to work multiple instances on the same page with custom options.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82b4m1zp/) which allows for multiple panzooms all with the same class.

```js
const paths = document.querySelectorAll('.content-image-module .image-pinch img')
    paths.forEach(Panzoom)
```

```css
.image-pinch {
    min-height: 360px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 414px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
}

img {
        width: initial;
        max-width: 2000px;
        position: initial;
        -webkit-transform: initial;
        -ms-transform: initial;
        transform: initial;
        max-width: initial;
        cursor: crosshair;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@panzoom/panzoom@4.4.1/dist/panzoom.min.js"></script>
<section class="content-image-module">
  <div class="image-pinch">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622495505508-03991221aca7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1934&q=80"/>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="content-image-module">
  <div class="image-pinch">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622495505508-03991221aca7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1934&q=80"/>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="content-image-module">
  <div class="image-pinch">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622495505508-03991221aca7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1934&q=80"/>
  </div>
</section>
```

However I can't figure out how to add any custom options to it?

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xc47k65/), which has my custom options, but I can't get it to work alongside the `forEach` and work with multiple instances with the same class on the same page. You can see in the fiddle how only the first one works.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('.content-image-module .image-pinch img')
    const panzoom = Panzoom(elem, {
        maxScale: 5,
        minScale: 1,
        maxScale: 3,
        contain: 'outside',
        disableZoom: false,
    })
```

```css
.image-pinch {
    min-height: 360px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 414px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
}

img {
        width: initial;
        max-width: 2000px;
        position: initial;
        -webkit-transform: initial;
        -ms-transform: initial;
        transform: initial;
        max-width: initial;
        cursor: crosshair;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@panzoom/panzoom@4.4.1/dist/panzoom.min.js"></script>
<section class="content-image-module">
  <div class="image-pinch">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622495505508-03991221aca7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1934&q=80"/>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="content-image-module">
  <div class="image-pinch">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622495505508-03991221aca7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1934&q=80"/>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="content-image-module">
  <div class="image-pinch">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622495505508-03991221aca7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1934&q=80"/>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue with the below:

```
const paths = document.querySelectorAll('.content-image-module .image-pinch img')
paths.forEach((elem) => {
    const panzoom = Panzoom(elem, {
        maxScale: 5,
        minScale: 1,
        maxScale: 3,
        contain: 'outside',
        disableZoom: false
    });
});
```